# Switch GUI icon from light to dark "theme" with PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, darkmode

I am developing a GUI based on PyQt5 (I'm using Qt creator 8.0.0 based on Qt6.3) and I want to update the icons when the user switches the application to "dark" or "light" mode (ie, icon is black png for light mode and white png for dark mode). The problem is that I can't access to buttons icon name, and so I can't redefine the new resource path according to light/dark mode.

Thanks in advance for your advice and help.

My strategy was quite simple : my icons are managed via the resources.qrc file under the prefixes "+theme_light" or "+theme_dark". By default the "light" theme is loaded. I manage the path of the icons by calling the select function on the QFileSelector instance after setting the extra selector on the currently selected theme. My idea was the following: when the user clicks on the "switch_mode" button, I browse all the QWidget instances of the window and if an icon has been assigned to them, I retrieve the path/name of the icon to redefine it with the new theme.
The problem I'm having is that I can't access the name of my icon, so I can't redefine the new resource path.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.
PS : I have a style file that manages the appearance of the interface but for simplicity here I have just applied a white or black background colour depending on the theme.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.frame = QWidget()
        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.styles = {
            "0": ["theme_dark", "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"],
            "1": ["theme_light",  "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"]
        }
        
        self.frame.switch_btn.clicked.connect(self.switchMode)

        # Apply default light_theme icons
        self.selector = QFileSelector()
        ex_selectors = [self.styles["1"][0]]
        self.selector.setExtraSelectors(ex_selectors)
        self.frame.pushButton_1.setIcon(QIcon(self.selector.select(":/open_eye")))
        self.frame.pushButton_2.setIcon(QIcon(self.selector.select(":/close_eye")))

        # Test access icon name **-> Get icon object id but nothing for name**
        print("BTN 1", self.frame.pushButton_1.icon(), "  path", self.frame.pushButton_1.icon().name())
        print("BTN 2", self.frame.pushButton_2.icon(), "  path", self.frame.pushButton_2.icon().name()) 

    def switchMode(self, checked:bool):
        # Change frame background color
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(self.styles[str(int(checked))][1])
        # Get all objects in main window if is instance of QWidget
        children_objects = [
            child for child in self.centralWidget().children()
            if isinstance(child, QWidget)
        ]
        # Change main window children background color
        for obj in children_objects :
            obj.setStyleSheet(obj.styleSheet()+self.styles[str(int(checked))][1])
             # 1. Get obj icon
            try :
                 ic = obj.icon()
                 if not ic.isNull() :  # Check if object icon is not Null
                    ic_name = ic.name()
                    print("i name  ", i_name)  **# print empty string**
                    # Change icon to dark theme icon
                    ex_selectors = [self.styles[str(int(checked))][0]]
                    self.selector.setExtraSelectors(ex_selectors)
                    obj.setIcon(QIcon(self.selector.select(":/"+ic_name)))
            except:
                pass # Obj icon not set
```

And the resources.qrc file :

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/+theme_dark">
        <file alias="open_eye">rsc/icons/openeye_d.png</file>
        <file alias="close_eye">rsc/icons/closeeye_d.png</file>
    </qresource>
    <qresource prefix="/+theme_light">
        <file alias="open_eye">rsc/icons/openeye_l.png</file>
        <file alias="close_eye">rsc/icons/closeeye_l.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And the "ugly" GUI test window :
[my ugly light mode window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT5kF.png)
This allowing to check if initial resource paths are right,  I can see the open_eye and close_eye icons on QPushbuttons.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you create two separate icon themes and then switch them with [`QIcon.setThemeName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#setThemeName)?

Comment: Thanks @musicamante, actually until now I couldn't use fromTheme() and setThemeName() (Icons didn't show up initially on the buttons, probably path issue). I just succeeded in applying this example  (https://openapplibrary.org/dev-tutorials/qt-icon-themes) by using directly the index.theme file of the "zafiro" pack. If I understand correctly I have to create myself this index.theme file to generate my dark and light theme, then when the user clicks on "switch_mode" just call the QIcon.setThemeName("selected_theme_name") method to directly update the paths of icons? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Creating the theme file is a bit cumbersome at first, but once you get the gist, it's quite easy, and using `fromTheme()` is simpler than always using the full path, with the major benefit that once you use this method, icons don't need to be updated again, as setting the icon theme will automatically switch all icons accordingly.

Comment: It's perfect and it looks much more optimized than my initial idea. I'll try to generate the theme files and update the post when it works. Thanks a lot for your precious help !

Answer (score 2):

As @musicamante suggested, I solved the problem by generating theme files and calling the QIcon.setThemeName("selected_theme_name") method to actually update the paths of the icons used in the application.
Here the light index.theme file (very simplified for the test, and just change the name for the dark theme):

```
    [Icon Theme]
    Name= Light
    Comment=An example icon light theme
    
    Directories= test,
    
    [test]
    Size=24
    Context=Actions
    Type=Fixed
```

(This link seems to be a good start point to understand .theme file : https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html)

The files are in 2 separate directories (named "light" and "dark") each containing a "test" subdirectory that contains the png icons.

I then added the already existing directories to my resources.qrc file (right click then "Add Existing directory" where I select the index.theme files + the icons of each theme).

My resources file looks like this:

```
    <RCC>
        <qresource prefix="/icons">
            <file>dark/test/closeeye.png</file>
            <file>dark/test/openeye.png</file>
            <file>dark/index.theme</file>
            <file>light/test/closeeye.png</file>
            <file>light/test/openeye.png</file>
            <file>light/index.theme</file>
        </qresource>
    </RCC>
```

I think I understood why until now I could not set my icons with fromTheme. When adding files to the resources file the default prefix is `/` but it seems Qt searches for icons in a theme (QIcon.themeSearchPaths()) from `:/icons` (explained here : https://openapplibrary.org/dev-tutorials/qt-icon-themes). So I changed the prefix to `/icons/`.

I haven't yet found a way to define icons from the theme directly via QtDesigner but here is the modified code and it works, icons are directly updated when the user clicks on switch_mode (and now I have [my ugly dark mode window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS0NH.png) .

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.frame = QWidget()
        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self.frame)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.styles = {
            "0": ["dark", "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"],
            "1": ["light",  "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"]
        }
        self.frame.switch_btn.clicked.connect(self.switchMode)

        # Apply default light_theme icons
        QIcon.setThemeName(self.styles["1"][0])
        self.frame.pushButton_1.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("closeeye"))
        self.frame.pushButton_2.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("openeye"))

    def switchMode(self, checked:bool):
        # Change frame background color
        self.frame.setStyleSheet(self.styles[str(int(checked))][1])
        # Get all objects in main window if is instance of QWidget
        children_objects = [
            child for child in self.centralWidget().children()
            if isinstance(child, QWidget)
        ]
        # Change main window children background color
        for obj in children_objects :
            obj.setStyleSheet(obj.styleSheet()+self.styles[str(int(checked))][1])

        # Set QIcon new theme
        QIcon.setThemeName(self.styles[str(int(checked))][0])
```