# Switching icons when changing theme in my PyQt5 app

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, icons, themes

I am encountering an issue: I am trying to switch icons when the user changes the app theme (light-dark). I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74432913/switch-gui-icon-from-light-to-dark-theme-with-pyqt5) step by step, where the main difference between my code and the provided solution is that the latter switches icons for QPushButton objects, while I am attempting the same with QAction objects used in a menu bar in my app. I set the default theme when initializing the app, and then the user can change it anytime by clicking a button.

The problem is that the app is not uploading the icons (at least not when using QIcon.fromTheme). If I use QIcon(':/icons/<icon_name>.') it does works only in uploading the icons but not changing between ligh-mode icons to dark-mode icons and vicecersa so I do have two problems with my code.

this is my code (MRE) and how I am tackling this task:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QToolBar,
    QStatusBar,
    QPushButton,
    QStackedWidget
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from Btns.btns import QActionBtn
import qtstylish
import resources_rc
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # light theme selected by default
        self.selected_theme_option = 'light'
        QIcon.setThemeName(self.selected_theme_option)
        self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light())

        # creating widgets
        self.light_dark_switch = QPushButton('Click to change theme')
        self.container = QStackedWidget(self)
        self.menu = self.menuBar()
        self.file = self.menu.addMenu('&File')
        self.submenu = self.file.addMenu('New')
        self.toolbar = QToolBar(self)
        self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(32, 32))
        self.first_qactionbtn = QActionBtn(
            icon=QIcon.fromTheme('cotizacion'),
            text='Cotizacion',  # btn label
            parent=self,
            statustip='Create a new quotation'
        )
        self.second_qactionbtn = QActionBtn(
            icon=QIcon.fromTheme('recibo'),
            text="Recibo",
            parent=self,
            statustip='Create a new receipt'
        )
        
        # connecting signal to slot
        self.light_dark_switch.clicked.connect(self.switching_dark_light_mode)

        ####### BUILDING THE MAINWINDOW #######
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(800, 800))

        self.container.addWidget(self.light_dark_switch)

        self.submenu.addAction(self.first_qactionbtn)
        self.submenu.addAction(self.second_qactionbtn)

        self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar)

        self.toolbar.addActions([self.first_qactionbtn, self.second_qactionbtn])

        self.setStatusBar(QStatusBar(self)) 

    # methods
    def switching_dark_light_mode(self):
        if self.selected_theme_option == 'light':
            self.selected_theme_option = 'dark'
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.dark())
        else:
            self.selected_theme_option = 'light'
            self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light())
        QIcon.setThemeName(self.selected_theme_option)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

my resources.qrc file contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource prefix="icons">
        <file>Icons/dark/test/cotizacion.svg</file>
        <file>Icons/dark/test/recibo.svg</file>
        <file>Icons/dark/index.theme</file>

        <file>Icons/light/test/cotizacion.svg</file>
        <file>Icons/light/test/recibo.svg</file>
        <file>Icons/light/index.theme</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

and my index.theme files contain this:

```
[Icon Theme]
Name= Light  <-- this changes to Dark for the second index.theme file
Comment=An example icon light theme

Directories= test,

[test]
Size=32
Context=Actions
Type=Fixed
```

also I put in here my requeriments.txt file:

```
numpy==1.26.2
pandas==2.1.3
Pillow==10.1.0
psutil==5.9.6
PyMuPDF==1.23.7
PyMuPDFb==1.23.7
PyPDF2==3.0.1
PyQt5==5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.13.0
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.6
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5==5.15.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
qtstylish==0.1.5
reportlab==4.0.7
setuptools==68.2.2
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
```

I must say that I am using qtstylish as the package to display the light and dark mode in my app. I am not sure if it could be a problem

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is the actual issue? You haven't described any specific problems.

Comment: It's unclear, and the example is ambiguous (there's no `balloon` file in the resource list, and we don't know what `QActionBtn` does). You also say that it doesn't to work with actions, but you never say if it *does* work for buttons - there's no QButton, btw). Please provide a valid [mre], and ensure that the theme is properly loaded, possibly switching the theme names in the theme files (to see if the selected theme *does* load the correct files, as it's possible that the fallback mechanism of QIcon just attempts to load the first available icon if the theme is not loaded correctly).

Comment: @ekhumoro you are right! I have already edited my question! The main problem is that my app does not upload the icons using QIcon.fromTheme. If I use another way, like using QIcon("resourcePath"), it does! so I think the problem is related with .fromTheme method or maybe with the index.theme file

Comment: @musicamante ok, let me try if with a QPushButton works in mi case! Yes, I have already edited my question. Balloon is an icon I was testing with because of its format (it is a png file) and still does not work! so It is not a problem with icons format. I am going to follow you recommendation and try to provide a minimal reproducible example (I am new in stack overflow). Give me some minutes

Comment: @musicamante I have already edited my answer and post a MRE. I tried using a QPushButton instead a QAction object and it did not work. I also wrote the content of my requeriments file and I also highlighted that I am using a package to display light-dark mode to my app. Thanks in advance

Comment: @IsmaelSantana You clearly ***did not*** follow the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74435685/984421) "step by step". In particular, your resource file has obvious differences. As [stated in the QIcon docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#themeSearchPaths), Qt looks for a directory under `:/icons`, but your code doesn't do that. It sets the theme path to `:/icons/dark`, which obviously doesn't exist (since you've inserted an extra directory). When calling `QIcon.setThemeName()`, you must pass in a *valid relative path* to a directory that contains an *index.theme* file.

Comment: @ekhumoro it was not the issue. I have already found the problem. What I did was to change the name of my icons folder from Icons to icons (because as you say: Qt searches icons in a folder called icons in lowercase) and changed the prefix of my resources.qrc file to "/" as the author o fthis article pointed: https://openapplibrary.org/dev-tutorials/qt-icon-themes. Anyway thank you very much for your comments!

Comment: @IsmaelSantana Yes, it is the issue. The prefix "/" makes no difference at all, so you can just remove it completely. As I said, all that matters is that you pass in the *correct relative path* when setting the theme name. With a directory structure of `icons/dark/index.theme`, using the relative path `dark` will resolve to `:/icons/dark`, which now ***does*** exist (since you renamed `Icons` to `icons`). So you have arrived at exactly the same solution I gave in my previous comment.